# BASH MYSQL FETCH FIELDS

Tags: mysql, bash

i have this code:

```
for file in $(ls  -I *.bad1 -I *.bad2 $1); do
    query="select file_name,dest_path,new_file_name from FILES where            
          file_name='"${file%%\_*}"'" 
    while read -a row
    do
        name="${row[0]}"
        dest="${row[1]}"
        new_name="${row[2]}"
        echo $name
        echo $dest
        echo $new_name
   done < <(echo $query  | mysql -N -u root -pcorollario86 -D test)
done
```

It work but the select statement i need is:

```
select max(file_name),max(dest_path),max(new_file_name) from FILES where            
          file_name='"${file%%\_*}
```

because i have to compare the return value of each field from the statement **(>0 or =0)**.

The problem is that when i use this second statement BASH give me an error
 regard the use of aggregation function.

I DON'T NEED TO PRINT EACH FIELDS. I NEED TO FETCH EACH FIELD INTO A VARIABLE.

Exists another way to fetch every single field from select statement into single variable?
Any suggestion please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should *really* be using a different language for this.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Which languages do you know?

Comment: I know a little bit of python. But i need to practice with bash. I have an exercise: i have to take some files(except .bad1 and .bad2) from an input directory. Then i have to check if these files are in a table of mysql database. If they match i have to mv this files in other directory indicated in the same table of db. if they doesn't match i have to insert a warning in another table. So when they match i have no problem. But when they doesn't match mysql return no record. So with max function mysql homewever  return one record.It is impossible to do with bash?